# C#, read / write separation and properties. Pattern required

Tags: c#, properties, design-patterns

Ok, so C# has properties

```
public int Prop {get;set;}
```

I can put the getter and the setter on separate interfaces like this:

```
public interface IRead
{ int AnInt { get; } }

public interface IWrite
{ int AnInt { set; } }
```

And then mix and match them like so:

```
public class WorkingClass : IRead, IWrite
{
    public int AnInt { get; set; }
}
```

Where it starts to go wrong is where I might have a base object.

```
public class BaseClass : IRead
{
    private int _anInt;

    public BaseClass(int anInt)
    { _anInt = anInt; }

    public virtual int AnInt
    { get { return _anInt; } }
}
```

I then want a derived class which can write as well.

```
public class Derived : BaseClass, IWrite //bits elided
{
    public override int AnInt
    {
        get { return base.AnInt; }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); } //<-- error
    }
}
```

Which of course doesn't work.

This actually doesn't come up that often. I prefer to have methods with change state and have properties read only. This is design 101 I guess, but as a contrived example, I'd have an Age property with just a get and then a method called IncreaseAge.

So with that all in mind. If you did want to have a mutable object with seperate read and write interfaces how would you do it?

I could do it in a Java-esque way with separate getter/setter methods on each interface. But that negates the benefits of properties + one of the cop programs will yell at me.

Comment: I have not comp on my hands now and can not try, but what if you don't override BaseClasse's virtual method in Derived, but only esplicitly implement IWrite interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the base setter protected and have the derived class implement `IWrite` explicitly delegating to the base setter:

```
public class BaseClass : IRead {
  public BaseClass(int anInt) { AnInt = anInt; }

  public int AnInt {
    get; protected set;
  }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass, IWrite {
  public Derived(int anInt) : base(anInt) { }

  int IWrite.AnInt {
    set { base.AnInt = value; }
  }
}
```

(The keyword `base` can even be omitted and the base property doesn't need to be `virtual`.)

Comment: so it does, Thanks :) I feel silly for not realising, but there you go :)